# Assign Master Page to Nested Master Page from Code Behind

Tags: nested, master-pages

I have a parent MasterPage (Main.master) and a child NestedMasterPage

In the NestedMasterPage i have assigned the MasterPageFile property in the html code like below

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Themes/ABC/Main.Master" CodeBehind="User_Main.master.cs" Inherits="ProjectABC.UI.Pages.MasterPages.User_Main" %>
```

Now in the code behind of the NestedMasterPage i am trying to change the MasterPageFile property to some other MasterPage but its not working.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPageFile = "~/Themes/XYZ/Main.Master";
}
```

No code error, just the HTML assigned path is working and not the code behind. What am i missing???

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this issue is that the `PreInit()` event of a master page file is never called in the asp.net page life cycle. You can see the complete set of master and contebnt page events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx).

You can set the master page of a child master page in the content page's `PreInit()` event in the following way:

```
public partial class TestMaster : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the master page file of the current pages master.
        this.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMasterPage.master";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost went berserk in not solving this issue. Your help worked. Thanks a lot